# Putting Data Frames into Complex Hierachical Lists in For-Loop (r)

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, hierarchy

I have created a list hierarchy, and now I'm trying to put data frames into those lists, but I'm not sure of the syntax that allows me to put a data frame into a list.

Essentially what I'm trying to acheive is this:

```
PlanetList[["Mars"]][["Mars  vs  Venus"]]["PlanetDataFrame"] <- CurrentDataFrame
```

Which goes well, provided that I have run the loop once so that it fails but still applies a data frame to the `CurrentDataFrame` variable for me to mess about with.

But in my for-loop like this:

```
PlanetList[[Planets[i]]][[vsList]]["PlanetDataFrame"] <- CurrentDataFrame
```

It doesn't apply my data table to the correct folder, in fact from what I can tell it's making a new one and writing into that.

I can't work out what to change, but I'm assuming the above line of code is the crux of my problem.

Here's the full for-loop:

```
for(i in 1:length(Planets)) {
  for(j in 1:length(Planets)) {    

  #here I create the 'X vs Y' (e.g. Mars vs Venus) variable to 
  #direct my newly retrieved data frame into the correct sublist
  #later on
  vsList <- paste0(Planets[i], ' vs ', Planets[j])

  #obviously - file path. All good here. 
  FilePath <- file.path(paste0(SourceDir, '/', Planets[i]))

  #get my data frame full of exciting numbers
  PlanetDataFrame <- read_delim(file.path(paste0(FilePath, "Correlations_file_for_", Planets[i], '_vs_', Planets[j], '_threshold_0.0.txt')), ' ', trim_ws = TRUE, col_names = FALSE)      

#put that data frame in a corresponding list (or not)
PlanetList[[Planets[i]]][[vsList]]["PlanetDataFrame"] <- PlanetDataFrame

}

}
```

Additional Issue: Not only is this creating a new list entirely and ignoring those I have already made, but I also get the following warning:

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I made this list hierachy using the following:

```
Planets = c('Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune')
DataSets <- c('PlanetDataFrame', 'PlanetMatrix', 'PlanetTable')


PlanetList <- lapply(Planets, function(el_PlanetList_outer) {
  ## create a list with |Planets| elements
  ## this we do by creating first an inner list vector(.)
  ## and the repeating it |Planets| times
  ret <- rep(tibble(setNames(vector("list", length(DataSets)), 
                           DataSets)), 
             length(Planets))
  setNames(ret, ## ret has no proper names yet
           paste(el_PlanetList_outer, " vs ", Planets)) 
})
names(PlanetList) <- Planets ## could have been done with setNames as well
str(PlanetList)
```

I thought that specifying 'tibble' rather than 'list' (6th line of text down in the above bloc) would allow me to put a dataframe in there?

I apologise as this may have now turned this question into a bit of a hydra which wasn't my original intent.

So in the hope, all the information required to help me is presented above,  and at the risk of wasting a few hundred more bits:

All I'm trying to achieve is to retrieve a file like this:

```
Correlations_file_for_Saturn_vs_Mercury_threshold_0.0.txt
```

And then pop it neatly into it's correct list / sublist:

```
PlanetList > Saturn > Saturn vs Mercury > PlanetDataFrame
```

An abbreviated view of my file hierarchy showing the first planet:

```
Planet List -
             |
             |-- Mercury -
             |            |
             |            |-- Mercury vs Venus - 
             |            |                     |
             |            |                     |--PlanetDataFrame
             |            |                     | 
             |            |                     |--PlanetMatrix
             |            |                     |
             |            |                     |--PlanetTable
             |            |                     |
            ...          ...                   ...
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to modify `PlanetList[[Planets[i]]][[vsList[i]]]["PlanetDataFrame"] <- PlanetDataFrame` by `PlanetList[[Planets[i]]][[vsList]]["PlanetDataFrame"] <- PlanetDataFrame` because you have `vsList <- paste0(Planets[i], ' vs ', Planets[j])` in your for-loop

Comment: You're quite right that was a mistake, but unfortunately, that wasn't the main problem.

Comment: And try replacing `PlanetList[[Planets[i]]][[vsList]]["PlanetDataFrame"] <- PlanetDataFrame` by `PlanetList[[Planets[i]]][[vsList]][["PlanetDataFrame"]] <- PlanetDataFrame` or by `PlanetList[[Planets[i]]][[vsList]]$PlanetDataFrame <- PlanetDataFrame`.

Comment: Awesome! Progress! So now there are no error messages, except I have duplicates of all my 'vs' folders. So, for instance, I have the original empty 'Mars vs Venus', and a new 'Mars vs Venus' complete with the data frame. Would you be able to help me overwrite the original? And thank you very much for getting me this far, I was stuck in a rut.

Comment: Not sure, but why don't write `PlanetList <- list()` instead of `PlanetList <- lapply(...)` before the for-loop ? Also, even if it does not matter you have "Jupiter" twice in your Planets vector.

Comment: In fact, you have duplicated because "vs id" are not exactly the same between your `lapply` function and your for loop : you use `paste` and `" vs "` so there 2 spaces on each side of "vs" in the lapply, and you use `paste0` and  also `" vs "`. So, there is only one space on each side of "vs" in the loop. So id are different and you create new objets in the loop (that you considere as duplicates). Not sure to be clear, don't hesitate to tell me if not !

Comment: @Pelilican, Good Lord you are a gem. Thank you so much for helping me, I'm new to all this and if it wasn't for help from people like you I'd be utterly stranded (for instance I didn't appreciate the difference between `paste` and `paste0` at all). If you are so inclined you can assemble all your help into an answer which I will mark as my solution. It might not be very exciting, so if you'd rather spend your time helping other people I'll do it for the anyone who stumbles across my question in the future. Thank you very much for your help.